# How do you test an Android application across multiple processes?

Tags: android, testing, automation, robotium

I have the whole project for tablets with resources and already have bunch of test cases written in combination of Robotium, Android and JUnit APIs

In a project which under testing is used special attribute for one of activities `android:process=":remote"`. At the point where activity with this attribute already loaded I can use Robotium methods but can't get access to the elements on current screen. So seems like I should relaunch instrumentation or initialize new instance of `Solo`. I tried to do this, but no help, seems like I can't relaunch it in other process from my test. Maybe someone have an experience of testing such kind of applications and know how to implement it with `Robotium` or using directly android.test API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IUAutomator, but it works on api >= 16:
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

You can always use monkey runner:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html
however it's based on x,y

There is no option to use robotium, neither instrumentation to test multiple processes.

Comment: Actually I have the whole project with resources and already have bunch of test cases written in combination of Robotium, Android and JUnit APIs. "neither instrumentation to test multiple processes" did you mean ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 or all available Instrumentations?

Comment: instrumentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html

from ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 you can get this with:
getInstrumentation()

Comment: @masterz I know this API, I tried to relaunch Solo using this methods, what you suggest ??

Comment: Forget using robotium for multiprocess application. Android test framework doesn't support it too.